How to exit the adb sideload?
I accidentally chose to apply a package with adb sideload. How to exit the adb sideload?
I have tried pressing the power button and volume up. But it's not working in my tablet.

Pressing and holding power button on most devices forces a reboot. Depending on the device you need to press the power button 10-60 seconds.

If you still have the command prompt open, press "CTRL+C" to cancel a command, then type adb kill-server and close the command prompt.
If you don't have that, press and hold Volume Down and the power button (As per comment above).

If the process is already initiated, don't interrupt it. Wait for it to cancel then manually exit recovery.
